# Is there a way to delete data uploaded today from an index in elasticsearch/kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to delete data that has been pushed today into elasticsearch index named **index1**. How to do so?

My index looks like this :

```
 {
    "_index" : "index1",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "zIRLIB9H5oRSfavviZ",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "ramen",
      "class" : "5",
      "age" : "12",
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "index1",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "zYRLI3IBoRSfawviy",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "tom",
      "class" : "6",
      "age" : "51",
   }
 }
```

I want to delete the second set of data which is pushed today so that my index looks like this :.

```
 {
    "_index" : "index1",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "zIRLIB9H5oRSfavviZ",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "ramen",
      "class" : "5",
      "age" : "12",
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can delete the index altogether then just run

```
DELETE index1
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep the index but delete everything in there, run

```
POST index1/_delete_by_query?q=*
```

And if you want to keep the index because you have data from other days and only want to delete the data from today, then you can do

```
POST index1/_delete_by_query?q=@timestamp:[now/d TO *]
```

(Make sure to replace `@timestamp` by your data field)

Comment: in my index I have many fields... is there a way to delete all at once?

Comment: An index contains documents and documents contain fields. What fields are you talking about?

Comment: In my index named index1, I have fields like name,class,age... I want to delete all of them which I inserted today..

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the index **mapping** then. Well, once a field has been added to a mapping there's no way to remove it. You need to create another index with the proper mapping and reindex your data into that new index

Comment: I don't need to remove the fields , I need to delete the records into that field... For example:  name,class,age are the columns having total of 100 rows of records... 10 of which are inserted today... So, I want to delete that 10 rows of records..

Comment: Maybe show a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve (doc before, doc after)

Comment: Ok, so you want to delete a document, but you don't have any date in that document, so there's no way to know that it has been created today...